# how to accept multiple strings in an array in C (using Turbo C++ V3.0) and sort them according to the count of vowels each contain

Tags: c, arrays, character

I need the user to enter Sentences and store them in an array and then count the number of vowels in each string of each index of array, and print the sorted o/p according to count of vowels

For example:

```
char z[10][10]  // this will store sentences in array
```

but I can't figure out how to match each sentence with vowels

```
z[i]=='a' || (all vowels)
```

would work, but how do I make each string to go under the check?

Here is code I havee been trying:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main(){
    int i, j;
    int count;
    char z[10][100];
    clrscr();
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter a string: ");
        //scanf("%[^\t\n]s", z[i]);
        gets(z[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        count = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < 100; j++)
        {
            if (z[i][j] == 'a')
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("%d",count);
    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply iterate over every element of the array and over every character of each string.

```
int totalVocalCount = 0;
int numberOfWords = 10;
int numberOfLetters = 100;
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfWords; i++)
{
    int wordVocalCount = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < numberOfLetters; j++)
    {
        if(z[i][j] == 'a' || ... || z[i] == 'u')
            wordVocalCount++;
            totalVocalCount++;
    }
    printf("word %s has %d vocals",z[i], wordVocalCount);
}
printf("all words together have %d vocals",totalVocalCount);
```

Comment: i tried the suggested code @Theolodis

#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main(){
int i,j;
int count=0;
char z[10][100];
clrscr();
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
printf("\nEnter a string: ");
//scanf("%[^\t\n]s",z[i]);
gets(z[i]);
}
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
for(j=0;j<10;j++){
if(z[i]=='a'){count++;}
}
}


printf("%d",count);
getch();

}


its not working !! - shows count as 0

Comment: @user3575666 dude are you kidding me? I edited my answer

Comment: here is the code  (how do i comment a code - to make it look like a code ? )



     #include<stdio.h>
    #include<conio.h>

    void main(){
    int i,j;
    int count=0;
    char z[10][100];
    clrscr();
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
    printf("\nEnter a string: ");
    //scanf("%[^\t\n]s",z[i]);
    gets(z[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    for(j=0;j<10;j++){
    if(z[i]=='a'){count++;}
    }
    }


    printf("%d",count);
    getch();


    }

Comment: @user3575666 I wrote you a sample that you'd have to integrate. Of course it would not compile because I can't know for example how many words you have. But now I improved the answer to make it easier to integrate I hope.

Comment: i guess - its still not showing the count !! - its still displaying zero

somwhow i am not able to post the code like you did ?

how do i post my code like you did in comment ?

Comment: @user3575666 post the code in your question please, that way it will be better readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(){
    int i, j;
    char z[10][100];
    char ch;
    int vowels[10]={0};
    int rank[10];
    int n = 3;

    clrscr();
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("\nEnter a string: ");
        //scanf("%99[^\n]", z[i]);
        gets(z[i]);
        for(j=0;ch=z[i][j];++j){
            ch = tolower(ch);
            if(ch == 'a' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'u' || ch == 'e'|| ch == 'o')
                vowels[i] += 1;
        }
        rank[i] = i;
    }
    //sort
    for(i=0;i<n-1;++i){
        for(j=i+1;j<n;++j){
            if(vowels[i] < vowels[j]){
                int tmp   = rank[i];
                rank[i]   = rank[j];
                rank[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;++i){
        int pos = rank[i];
        printf("%d : %s\n", vowels[pos], z[pos]);
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```